# Rails3 ActiveRecord, 2 level result access

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have some AR models

```
User
 has_many :clients, :through => :users_to_clients
 has_many :files

Client
 has_many :users_to_clients
 has_many :users, :through => :users_to_clients
 has_many :files

File
 belongs_to :client
 belongs_to :user
```

and try to fetch all files, trough clients assigned to user

```
u = User.includes(:clients => :xls_files).find(1)
```

This code fire 3 sql query. In final sql looks like what i need he fecth all files trough clients on user.

```
SELECT "files".* FROM "files" WHERE "files"."client_id" IN (1, 2)
```

but how to get this data, if u variable just contain User object?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
User
    has_many :files
    has_many :clients, :through => :files

Client
    has_many :files
    has_many :users, :through => :files

File
    belongs_to :users
    belongs_to :clients
```

Then you can do stuff like `@user.clients` and `@client.users`

I can't tell from your post, but you may have to switch the client and file models around, so client belongs to users and files, depending on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any solution so i made it by hand by adding scope in File model

```
scope :by_user_clients, lambda { |user| where(client_id:
user.clients.pluck(:id)) }


File.by_user_clients(@user)
```